# Hhow can I use AVCapureSession in ARKit for clicking high quality pictures along with ARSession

Tags: swift, avfoundation, augmented-reality, arkit, avcapturesession

I am using ARKit for some model placement and then I want to click pictures in high quality as we do in AVFoundation. `ARCaptureSession` outputs photo,  but I am not able to find a way to make them both work together.

Comment: What is wrong with ARFrame? Different resolution?

Comment: @MaximVolgin yes

Comment: What exactly happens when you try using it them both? Maybe post some code?

Comment: @MaximVolgin  it gives me error that ARSession cannot be initialised

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arconfiguration/2942261-supportedvideoformats

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53287693/using-arkit-to-capture-high-quality-photos